# Partial build of project in qt instead of rebuilding the whole project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, mingw32

How can i stop rebuilding the whole project when there are only some changes in a small part of it like MSVS does? QMake just keeps rebuilding all the files.
Using qt 6.4.2 and qt creator.

Comment: For Qt6 you probably should have switched to use CMake instead of QMake however with that said I am not sure we can answer the question as it likely depends on your code.

Comment: what details should i mention so it'd be easier to answer? also: i thought i should do something like add -i parameter for incremental build in settings of qt project or something

Comment: You probably should spend 10 to 30 minutes and produce a [mcve] that replicates your problem in as small amount of code and qmake .pro files as possible but still is buildable so that people can test. For example does this happen in a project with exactly 2 source files and you modify only one of them. Does the other get forced to be rebuilt?

Comment: Either something is telling your QMake to rebuild all; or your dependencies are messed up.  Precompiled headers????

Answer (score 0):

> "QMake just keeps rebuilding all the files."

Running the `qmake` executable produces so-called `Makefile`s or projects, and it does not (re)build any of your files.

The compiler's so-called `make` program (without `q`) decides what to do with said `Makefile`s or projects.
**For example**, you probably did change some header-file that's included by most of (if not all) other files, which causes `make` to rebuild said other files.

Having that said, `qmake` adds a `clean` target, which if run by `make`, basically deletes previous build-result. **Hence,** check your `make` command-line to ensure you don't accidentally trigger that target, like:

```
make clean
```

**Note** that Qt-Creator's "Projects" tab allows edit of said command-line(s).